# Room temp batter for cheese cake?

Tags: batter, cheesecake

Does the cheese cake batter have to be at room temp before cooking? I’m using batter I saved in the fridge and just didn’t want cracks if I put it in before it was room temp.

Comment: You need to be clear about what sort of cheesecake you're making.  It sounds like maybe a baked one, but that's not clear.  You may want to post the full recipe

Comment: it's doesn't have to be anything, but the slower you change temp the less cracking you'll have. I find a baking sheet on top of the pan for the first 20 mins helps a lot, as does slightly lowering the temp and cooking slightly longer, broiling at the end if needed to give it the right color. That said, cracked cheesecake tastes good, don't worry too much about it, it will get eaten regardless.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using refrigerated batter, you'll need to increase the cooking time.

Cracking is more related to how you cooled the cheesecake than how you heated it up, so I wouldn't expect this to affect cracking either way.